# Script tags added via jQuery not visible in FireBug

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

I am adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain/somescript.js">` to the document head via jQuery. This is the code I use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
    $("head").append(s);
});
```

While the script seems to be working perfectly, I do not see the scripts in the head when I use FireBug to inspect document head. This snippet does not show the added script(s) either:

```
$('script[src]').each(function(){
    console.log(this.src);
});
```

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong here? What bothers me is the fact that I see other scripts in the head section that were lazy/dynamically loaded but not those that I added. Also wondering if it is OK to load scripts that manipulate DOM in the document ready function.

### UPDATE

Replacing the code from:

```
$("head").append(s);
```

to

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

fixes the problem. The resulting DOM appears correctly in FireBug and jQuery correctly returns the script tags that were added static/dynamically.

Comment: I believe this is normal. Firebug says "Warning. Script Panel inactive during page load - reload to see all sources". That suggests that only scripts available on page load can be debugged.

Comment: Can a jQuery guru verify that `<script>` added via `$.append` method do not get physically added to the DOM, and instead they are just `eval` uated?

Comment: Why don't you use $.getScript() ? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I think by default `$.getScript` tries to avoid the browser cache, which I don't want for this particular case.

Comment: Try `$(document.head).append(s);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found [this tip](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-41361589) on jQuery.com:

```
> It should be noted that any attempts to append script elements using this
> method will fail silently:
> $('#element').append("<script></script>");

>> Not exactly. Scripts will be evaluated first, and then discarded.
>> So, if you do this:
>> $('#element').append("<script>alert('hello');</script>");
>> You'll see the alert.
```

This probably means that the script is evaluated but not inserted in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You will see a request being made to the script in the `NET` tab but the `script` tag won't be visible when inspecting the DOM. This seems like a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1774) in FireBug.

Comment: Does this mean jQuery won't be able to select the script tags either?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Mozilla's 'jsd' debugger support. One workaround is post on the on the bug cited above:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1774

If jquery used eval() instead of script tag injection then you could debug this in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Test it in Chrome as well</strike> using the Right-click "Inspect Element" option to use the full debugger (view source will not show the script's modifications).  The <strike>elements</strike> HTML tab should show real-time changes to the DOM

Comment: my mistake, I was thinking of "Inspect Element" in Firefox w/ Firebug.  I'm testing it right now on a page with a slideshow, each time the slideshow transitions firebug updated the HTML tab to show the current DOM, and highlights the modified elements for ~1s