# InnerHTML <> JQuery.html() - Depends on its version

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

This was something that drive me crazy. I was using JQuery 1.9 for testing... I passing some HTML code including Script tag... and I search in the element for script elements and I found them. Something like:

```
var myHtml = '<div>...</div><script href="..."></script>';
var myElem = $('<div/>').html(myHtml);
var scripts = myElem.find('script');
//scripts.length == 1
```

But in production, I had older version (JQuery 1.7), and the `scripts.length` is 0... and the debugger show that the script was added in the header???

- [JsFiddle Example (JQuery 1.9.1)](http://jsfiddle.net/AxxvF/1/) 1 Script Found (script is inserted in the div)
- [JsFiddle Example (JQuery 1.7.2)](http://jsfiddle.net/AxxvF/2/) 0 Scripts Found (script is inserted in the header)

So the possible solution (very ugly) is detecting the scripts of the header before and after of this code run... or use 100% DOM

If you have any other solution much prettier in How to find the script elements in the piece of html code using JQuery earlier version(such as 1.7)???

**UPDATE**

I found a possible solution:
[JsFiddle Example (JQuery 1.7.2 + DOM)](http://jsfiddle.net/AxxvF/3/) 1 Script Found (script is inserted in the div)

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to do. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The behavior of jQuery regarding `<script>` tags is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075609/script-tags-added-via-jquery-not-visible-in-firebug

Comment: Why would you load a script like that when you can just use $.getScript or $.ajax?